# JavaScript: trying to use a class' function that for some reason doesn't run

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, class, ecmascript-6

```
class Menu {
  constructor(id, listButtons, title = null, visible = false) {
    this.id = id;
    this.listBtn = listButtons;
    this.title = title;
    this.visible = visible;
    this.SetVisible(this.visible);
  }

  SetVisible(visibility) {
    alert("SetVisible:" + visibility + " " + this.id)
    if (visibility) {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.listBtn.length; i++) {
        this.listBtn[i].style.display = "block";
      }
      this.title.style.display = "block";
      visible = visibility;
    } else {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.listBtn.length; i++) {
        this.listBtn[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      this.title = "none";
      visible = visibility;
    }
  }
}



function ToggleMainAbout() {
  alert("Toggle_Main_About");
  mainMenu.SetVisible(!mainMenu.visible);
  aboutMenu.SetVisible(!aboutMenu.visible);
}
```

This is my class and function.

The function **`ToggleMain`** runs and as I'm able to see from the alert but for some reason my function **`SetVisible`** in the class **`Menu`** doesn't show the alert and I don't know for what reason.

If I change the `SetVisible`'s input to 'true' instead of a variable it still doesn't work so it's not a problem of the variable

Comment: Where did `mainMenu` and `aboutMenu` instances at the bottom of your code come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create instances of the class first:

```
let mainMenu = new Menu("Main", ["List button 1", "List button 2"]);
let aboutMenu = new Menu("About", ["Home", "Back"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you create Menu class objects for accessing Menu methods using new keyword. Like this const mainMenu = new Menu().